# How can i use DataRepeater Control in Windows Form with XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datarepeater

I've Created a data set, but i don't know how to get this work :)

if anyone can help me, i will be really appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean with WinForms or ASP.NET? There's no data repeater in win forms.

Comment: it's windows form. there's in winform using power pack feature in VS2008, but is there alternative way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your Data Repeater's DataSource property equal to your DataSet or a specific DataTable within that dataset. Is there something more complicated than that?

Links on how to use a DataRepeater:

- http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Repeater-Control.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx

How to use a DataRepeater with XML

- http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/xml/article.php/c7183

Comment: how do i set the repeating template? how to populate data into them?

Comment: You first need to add it to your web page, then in your code behind just say myDataRepeater.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0]. Added some links above for data repeater info.

Comment: i have my button on the repeater, how can i use it? regular button click wont work :)